# Change instance of y to z in x(where x is a list)

Tags: python

I wrote a function that changes all instances of y to z in x (where x is a list) but somehow my code is not working. The outcome should have been [1, 'zzz', 3, 1, 'zzz', 3]. I attached my code below any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

def changeThem(x,y,z):
    replace = {y : z}
    for key, value in replace.items():
        x = x.replace(key, value)
    print(x)
changeThem(x,2,'zzz')
```

Comment: as other members explained; lists doesn't have a replace function but here is another tip:  in general when you like to transform/ manipulate a list then you need to iterate over that list items. read it item by item and do your conditional logic or use list comprehension, map or other pythonic ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code yields an `AttributeError`. This is because `list` does not have a `replace` method. `str` has a `replace` method, so this might be where you're getting confused.

You could accomplish this with a very simple list comprehension:

```
x = [z if e == y else e for e in x]
```

Essentially, the above list comprehension states:

> For every value e in the list x, replace it with z if the element is equal to y. Otherwise, just keep the element there.

It is also equivalent to the following:

```
result = []
for e in x:
    if e == y:
        result.append(z)
    else:
        result.append(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

A list does not have `.replace()` method. How about the following?

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

def changeThem(x,y,z):
    return [z if i == y else i for i in x]

print(changeThem(x, 2, 'zz'))
```

The function consists of just one line so defining this function might not be even necessary. But I am leaving it in case you would like to call it multiple times.